What is the mouse press and release event in Flet?
I am trying to learn Python Flet, but have I found that Flet Button only has a "press event" but no "release event". Where is the "release event"?
import flet as ft
import threading
import time
import asyncio

async def main(page: ft.Page):
    async def on_click(e):
        print("clicked")

    async def on_release(e):
        print("where is the release ?")

    page.add(
        ft.ElevatedButton("T", on_click=on_click)
    )

ft.app(main)

